# layout for article by css and get fields with php

Tags: drupal-7

I would insert some custom article in drupal. That every article,
some fields that I decided.
Then I would like these article are displayed with a graphic set from CSS.
So I would take for each article, the fields with php.

How do I post article with the graphics set to css? and how to take php variables?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I follow. Are you talking about adding fields to the article content type?

Comment: Yes, I want to add fields in my "content type" and I would take it with php in html / css page. I think that it is quite customizable display of a "custom content types"

Comment: Do you know about Drupal theming? What's your experience level?

Comment: no I just started recently. what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

From your answer to my comment it sounds like you would like to edit the article content type and then "theme" the resulting page.

You can add fields to any content type (or add new content types) in "Content Types" in the admin. Select the type you want (article) and click "Manage fields". Here you can add as many fields or whatever type as you like. Each field will be given a machine name, widget and there will be a wizard to follow that explains all the relevant options.

Once all your fields are added, click "Manage Display" to change the order and way the fields are displayed.

To add a template to your theme, create a folder in your themes folder called "templates". Then copy `node.tpl.php` from root/modules/node/ to this new folder. Rename the copied file to `node--machine_name.tpl.php`. So for the content type "article" you would change the file to `node--article.tpl.php`.

Clear your cache (admin/config/development/performance) and that content type will be using that new template. By default all fields will be displayed by this line of code `print render($content);` If you comment that line out you can display fields individually but taking the fields machine name and doing `<?php print render($content['field_page_image']); ?>`

Read up on Drupal theming, there are a lot of good docs out there.